# What's the {} in find /path/ -exec command '{}' do?

Tags: find

I'm curious as to what the {} in the following command is actually for?

**Example Command:**

`find /foo/ -name "*.txt" -exec rm -v {} \;`

The Man page provided a small blurb but it confused me a little bit:

> The string '{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed 
>   everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in
>   arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the symbol that gets replaced by the file name that `find` comes up with.

Comment: Ah that makes sense and could i add another argument after that?

Comment: You can add whatever you like: it is just an argument. pretty much like `"$a-single-output-file-name"` when `-exec` ends with `\;`  ... but it means `"$multiple"` `"$output"` `"$filenames"` when `-exec` ends with `\+`

Comment: Good comment by Peter.O :). See also related answer to [Question on find -exec](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)