# How to find and run a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, find, path

I have a script named `script.sh`. I don't know where it is in the file system, but I do know it exists.

How do I find the script, make it executable, and run it all in one line through the command line?

I would like to run it with a single command. Find, make executable and execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run find -exec?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Answer (score 8):

1. Use the `find` command for it in your home:

   ```
   find ~ -name script.sh
   ```
2. If you didn't find anything with the above, then use the `find` command for it on the whole F/S:

   ```
   find / -name script.sh 2>/dev/null
   ```

   (`2>/dev/null` will avoid unnecessary errors to be displayed) .
3. Launch it:

   ```
   /<whatever_the_path_was>/script.sh
   ```

And all at once would give; [more on how to find and exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec):

```
find / -name "script.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \; -exec {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

(beware if you have more than one "`script.sh`", it will run them all)

Comment: you can use `-iname` for _case insensitive_ search.

Comment: I would like to run it with a single command. Find, make executable and execute.

Comment: `find . -name script.sh -type f -exec bash {} \;`    otherwise if you wanted to make if executable first then `find . -name script.sh -type f -exec chmod +x {} \; -exec {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

There may be several scripts called exactly the same thing on your file system, so locating it based on the name and then blindly executing it is probably a very bad idea.

To locate it, use `find` as shown by J. Chomel in another answer to your question, or use `locate`:

```
$ locate script.sh
```

This will find all files called `script.sh` in locations that are readable by all users based on a database search on your system. Note that the database is updated on a regular basis (once daily or once weekly, depending on how it's configured), so files added since the last file system scan will not be found, but it's a lot faster than `find`.

You could use `select` to generate a menu from which you could select the correct script and execute it:

```
$ select script in $( locate script.sh ); do echo "$script"; break; done
```

Change `echo` to `command` to actually run the script you've selected rather than just printing its name.