# Find files that are not in .gitignore

Tags: grep, find, wildcards, git

I have find command that display files in my project:

```
find . -type f -not -path './node_modules*' -a -not -path '*.git*' \
       -a -not -path './coverage*' -a -not -path './bower_components*' \
       -a -not -name '*~'
```

How can I filter the files so it don't show the ones that are in .gitignore?

I thought that I use:

```
while read file; do
    grep $file .gitignore > /dev/null && echo $file;
done
```

but .gitignore file can have glob patterns (also it will not work with paths if file is in .gitignore), How can I filter files based on patterns that may have globs?

Comment: `man find` says: "-path pattern ... To ignore a whole directory tree, use -prune" so you want something like `find . -name .git -prune -o -name node_modules -prune -o -type f` (`-o` means "or")

Comment: @MilaNautikus the question was about gitignore not about find, that was just example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`git` provides [`git-check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to check whether a file is excluded by `.gitignore`.

So you could use:

```
find . -type f -not -path './node_modules*' \
       -a -not -path '*.git*'               \
       -a -not -path './coverage*'          \
       -a -not -path './bower_components*'  \
       -a -not -name '*~'                   \
       -exec sh -c '
         for f do
           git check-ignore -q "$f" ||
           printf '%s\n' "$f"
         done
       ' find-sh {} +
```

Note that you would pay big cost for this because the check was performed for each file.

Comment: What is `find-sh {} +` at the end?

Comment: @jcubic see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12902/38906

Comment: Ok, and what's `find-sh`?

Comment: @jcubic it's the name you gave for inline-sh script, so in case error occurs, you would have an meaningful error message

Comment: @jcubic Try `find /tmp -exec sh -c ': "${non_existed_var:?foo}"' find-sh {} +` for example

Comment: This solution is good, but need `git`. It would be awesome to have a generic solution for ignore files (.gitignore, .svnignore...).

Comment: Works as expected, but there is a typo. As the whole `for` loop is put into single quotes, we need to change `printf '%s\n' "$f"` to `printf "%s\n" "$f"`, otherwise `\n` is output as `n`.

Comment: Didn't git grep used to just work and ignore the things listed in .gitignore? I feel like I remember it did. Now it doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

To show files that are in your checkout and that are tracked by Git, use

```
$ git ls-files
```

This command has a number of options for showing, e.g. cached files, untracked files, modified files, ignored files etc.  See `git ls-files --help`.

Comment: I also think about `git ls-files` but don't think it has option to show untracked files, which one?

Comment: @cuonglm `-o` (other).  E.g., `git ls-files -o  -X .gitignore`

Comment: Ah yes, but can't handle the case where the file was tracked before but include in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Minor note: this does not list the actual files from the system but the files included in the git history. This can be a subtle difference on case-insensitive systems (e.g. Windows shares). Say, I committed ./foo.txt but then rename it to ./Foo.txt. Some git clients will not recognize this change and `git ls-files` outputs ./foo.txt while `find` would output ./Foo.txt

Answer (score 15):

there is a git command for doing exactly this: e.g.

```
my_git_repo % git grep --line-number TODO                                                                                         
desktop/includes/controllers/user_applications.sh:126:  # TODO try running this without sudo
desktop/includes/controllers/web_tools.sh:52:   TODO: detail the actual steps here:
desktop/includes/controllers/web_tools.sh:57:   TODO: check if, at this point, the menurc file exists. i.e. it  was created
```

As you stated, it will do a basic grep will most of the normal grep options, but it will not search `.git` or any of the files or folders in your `.gitignore` file.
For more details, see `man git-grep`

Submodules:

If you have other git repos inside this git repo, (they should be in submodules) then you can use the flag `--recurse-submodules` to search in the submodules as well

Comment: Great, it almost work because  I have other git repos inside current directory, that's why I have "*.git".

Comment: So I'm seeing this has stopped working for some reason. v 1.40

Comment: What I mean is that ignored but tracked files are not ignored.

Answer (score 6):

I think this works well:

```
git ls-files --cached --modified --other --exclude-standard
```

If you also want to recurse into submodules, add `--recurse-submodules`.

Comment: This works only for files that are tracked by git, the question doesn't say that it should only be files that are already in git.

Comment: No, `--other` also outputs those files which are not tracked by git (and then `--exclude-standard` removes those ignored by git).

Comment: It seems that files that are modified are duplicated on the list. So I would add `| uniq` at the end.

Comment: Then maybe just `--modified` should not be listed there?

Comment: `--deduplicate` should help with that.

Comment: `--recurse-submodules` doesn't seem compatible with all those flags

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array in which bash glob will be performed.

Having files like this :

```
touch file1 file2 file3 some more file here
```

And having an `ignore` file like this

```
cat <<EOF >ignore
file*
here
EOF
```

Using

```
arr=($(cat ignore));declare -p arr
```

Will result to this:

```
declare -a arr='([0]="file" [1]="file1" [2]="file2" [3]="file3" [4]="here")'
```

You can then use any technique to manipulate those data.

I personally prefer something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}(!($1 in a))'  <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}") <(find . -type f -printf %f\\n)
#Output
some
more
ignore
```

Comment: `gitignore` is superset of `bash` glob, you will miss for something like `!file*`

Comment: @cuonglm What do you mean by `!file*` ? As a glob pattern in ignore file or as a filename?

Comment: `gitignore` accept file pattern like `!file*` to exclude files start with `file`, and also double star `**`

Comment: `.gitignore` has a bunch of features, all of which might not be that easy to implement directly in Bash: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore . Though ignores consisting of just simple globs should be doable in plain Bash, without awk or such

Comment: @cuonglm You mean translation of `!` as not ? Maybe extended globing can handle this situation. About doublestar , bash can handle it with `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: No, you can't do it even with extended glob. it's `!(pattern)` in `bash`, not `!pattern`. And also for double star, like `!**`, `/**`

Comment: @cuonglm You are right about `extglob`. It has to be like `!(pattern)` and not `!pattern`. On the other hand, using `!file` in git maybe this means that git tools will fail to catch filenames starting with `!` ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou then escape `!` to match `!` literally.

Comment: @cuonglm OK. In git tools someone needs to escape `!` , in bash tools we need to add `( )` . In both cases you need a kind of "processing". In any case, since we talk about `.gitignore` there is no doubt that git tools should and will perform better than bash.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses metaprogramming heavily, but it's much faster than the answer marked correct by reducing repeated shell-command calls.

Replace `sed` deletion pattern with a substantial subset of your own known working-directory-level (`./`-starting) exclude list. Put the `*`-starting ones in the sed substitute pattern like normal find invocation (proper escaping plz).

```bash
FILES="$( \
  find . -depth 1 \
  | sed -e '/\/\.git/d' -e '/\/node_modules/d' \
      -e 's/.*/find '"'&'"' -type f/' \
  | sh \
)"
# >&2 echo debug: $FILES

HUGE_SED_COMMAND="$( \
  echo '/^('$( \
    git check-ignore --stdin <<<"$FILES" \
    | sed 's/\./\\./g; s/\//\\\//g' \
    )')$/d' \
  | sed 's/ /|/g' \
)"
# >&2 echo debug: $HUGE_SED_COMMAND

sed -E "${HUGE_SED_COMMAND}" <<<"$FILES"
```