# how to find the part of matching file in a directory and removing matched files from a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file named solution.txt . I need to check whether such file exist in current directory. if it exist, then removing that file and replacing it with (solution.txt)

Example:
in my directory:
wer.txt
wer1.txt
wer2.txt
solution1.txt
solution23.txt
solution32.txt

i need to remove all the files starting with 'solution' ending with txt from the directory and replace it with solution.txt.

please give the shellscript solution .

Answer (score 0):

you can try & adapt to remove all solution...txt files but not solution.txt if exist :

```
find . -type f -name "solution[0-9]*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

but you cannot have more than one file name solution.txt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is no what your asking, but here is my answer:

First you need to find those that you're looking for:
`find /file/where/you're/looking/at -name solution | grep txt`

Once you find them you can remove them with:
`rm thename23.txt thename34.txt`

Or merge them with (if you want to replace them at all use only one `>`):
`cat thename23.txt >> thename34.txt`

You also can use the `-exec` option of the `find` command. More info [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define what you meant by "replace them by solution.txt", but since you want to remove the other solution files first, I guess assume that you have the replacement file somewhere, otherwise the question doesn't make much sense.

I think the simplest way to do it would be

```
rm solution[0-9]*.txt >/dev/null && cp /from/somewhere/solution.txt .
```

This tries to remove the files, and if it succeeds, copies solution.txt to your working directory. With other words: You are guaranteed to have afterwards either no solution file at all, or a single one named solution.txt.

Note that this would also wipe out a file named solution5x.txt. I don't know whether this is acceptable for you. If this is an issue, you need to match the file names using a regular expression, for instance using `find ... -regex`.