# Move files by its size

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a little introductory exercise to do as homework, I have to do a little script which takes 2 arguments, first argument a directory the second argument a number.

The functionality is to classify the files from the directory into 2 subdirectories. First subdirectory for files larger than the second argument and the second subdirectory for smaller files.

My thought were to take $5 from ls -l but i think its not a good idea, can someone give me any recommendation? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest starting with the [Find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).  Then possibly taking a look at [How to run find -exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12902/237982).  Of course it's probably also a good idea if you make a stop [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/237982) before writing any shell scripts.

Comment: How about use find with 'size' parameter? It's very simple: find . -size [+-] <size>.

Comment: No need recursion AFAIK, if OP is a beginner, I think he should use basic conditions/algorithm, not advanced tools

Comment: @GillesQuenot:  I'm almost positive OPs teacher is trying to point him towards `find` with this objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, [don't parse ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

You can check file size with `stat -c '%s' file` (bytes) in a `for` loop. As a starter :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"

for file in *; do
    # code/tests here on each "$file"
done
```

Then you can use [*bash arithmetic*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) to do some conditions on file size.

Test by yourself to implement this, and feel free to edit (and/or comment) your post if you have some problems with code

---

Another solution (from comments), use [find](/questions/tagged/find) with the `-size` switch if you remember your teacher had talked of this tool, ex :

```
find "$1" -size +100
```

Check

```
man find | less +/-size
```