# grep -rlw but only on files that are as newer than 7 days?

Tags: grep, find

Currently, I use this version of grep -rlw

```
grep -rlw . -e "string_to_search"
```

To search for overall files containing "string_to_search".

I want to modify it to find files that are not older than 7 days.

How do I do it?

```
grep -rlw . -e "string_to_search" | find -mtime +7|print
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: Why not simply test it?

Comment: Ok this works.`find . -mtime -15 -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -lH "string_to_search" {} \;`/ Should I delete the question?

Comment: Just leave it ;-)

Comment: Why do you say `7` in the question and use `15` in the comment with what you claim to be a solution? Also the solution contains clauses that search for and work with gzipped files, the question didn't mention that. I would probably have done something like `find . -mtime -7 | xargs grep -lw "string_to_search_for"`.

Comment: Make it an answer @Henriksupportsthecommunity I'll accept it.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, `find -exec` is better than `find | xargs` in that it works with ugly filenames too (`xargs` by default processes e.g. spaces and quotes specially, not just newlines). Go with `find -exec grep ... {} +` to run a single grep for many files

Comment: Pretty much the same find+grep in [How to run find -exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12902/170373), and the general case of find+cmd is also mentioned in Mandatory Reading Question #1: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373) (or "Frequently given answer", or however you want to put it.)

Comment: `find` didn't have the `-exec ... +` syntax when I first learned of it, so I've never gotten used to it, if I need to handle ugly filenames I usually make `find` null-terminate the names (with `-print0`) and make `xargs` read the null-terminate (with `-0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use either `find` or `zsh` to find the files based on age to pass to `grep`.

- `find`:

  ```
  find . -mtime -7 -type f -exec grep -lFw string_to_search {} +
  ```
- `zsh`:

  ```
  grep -lFw -- string_to_search **/*(D.m-7)
  ```

Using `zsh` avoids the `./` prefix added to file paths and give you a sorted list but means we need the `--` (for non-POSIX `grep`s such as GNU `grep` or compatible) to guard against file paths that start with `-`. The `zsh` approach could hit the system's `execve()` limit on the size of arguments+environments which can be worked around using the `zargs` autoloadable function.

With the GNU implementations of `find`, `sort` and `xargs`, you can also avoid the `./` prefix and sort the list with:

```
find . -mtime -7 -type f -printf '%P\0' |
  sort -z |
  xargs -r0 grep -lFw -- string_to_search
```

`-mtime -7` and `m-7` match on files whose age (based on mtime) rounded down to an integer number of days (a day in this case being a duration of 86400 Unix seconds) is strictly less than 7. So that would be typically those last modified since same time same day last week (or in the future) except when there's been a DST change in the interval.

`-mtime +7` would be for ages strictly greater than 7, so for files 8 days (8 * 86400 seconds) old or older.